# Can I generate content in Jekyll from two different directories

Tags: jekyll

I have two pieces of somewhat unrelated source that I want to turn into one "site" using Jekyll.  But they are in two directories.  Let's say `PROJECT/site/` has the homepage and copy and so forth, and `PROJECT/clientlib/` has a bunch of libraries.  I'd like, for example, `PROJECT/site/index.md` to become `/index.html` and `PROJECT/clientlib/foo.js` to become `/clientlib/foo.js`

This is an open source project so I'd really like to avoid fooling around with symlinks or submodules that might make it harder for someone to check the project out and start using it.  And I want to be able to use the Jekyll dev server, without doing fixup on the generated files.

Is there a way to configure (or hack) Jekyll to get the layout I'm hoping for?

Answer (score 1):

I just finished publishing a custom gem that accomplishes this. It lets you specify a `shared_dir` that can be used between multiple Jekyll configurations for a common base:

https://github.com/sumdog/jekyll-multisite

Answer (score 0):

You can give them the same destination path in your _config.yaml file (in place of the default `_site`, see https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/Configuration

e.g.

```
destination: ../_site
```

but you will overwrite filenames, etc if they are duplicated between the two.